# Searching first level keys in a multidimensional hash Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash

I have the value of a multi-dimensional hash in Perl.

Its structure is

```
$hash{$key}{$field}{$date} = $value;
```

Given that I have both the correct value and field.

What is the fastest process possible to search for its key given that the value itself is unique (has a 1-1 relationship to the key)

EDIT:

I have added a third level which is date.
not all dates have a value but when it does, it is shared through all the  dates.

To simplify it, if it has a value, it is "A", else, blank.

Regards,
InnZaayynn

Comment: `$hash{$_}{$field} eq $value and print "=> $_\n" for keys %hash;` if you're searching for first level key.

Comment: Might want `print and last` there.

Comment: Yes, and regular foreach with block also (btw, there might be multiple first level keys which satisfy condition).

Comment: Doesn't that mean I have to iterate every possible key and check if its value is the same?

Comment: Yes, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: There are thousands of keys to check and also "value" has different values throughout dates (which is the third level I suppose) which I was unable to write above.

That's why I posted it here, just to check if there are a faster way of lookup on the first level instead of the iterating all keys.

Comment: Your issue seems quite unusual and I suspect it is subject to [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: hmm. actually I am searching for another answer that could be better than the usual iteration, if you know some, but if not, then I may be stuck with the slower solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145459/discussion-between-innzaayynn-and-27).

Comment: Well, the short answer is "you can't" - there's no way to check every key, without checking every key. Best you can do is break out of a loop half way, and on average you'll only have to check half.

Comment: @InnZaayynn: If this is the way you need to access your data structure, then you've designed the structure wrongly.

Comment: @Сухой27: You're missing a level. `$hash{$_}{$field}` is another hash reference.

Comment: Indeed, but question was edited in the mean time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The organization of your data is not suited to do a fast search. You're going to have to iterate through the entire hash. If you're going to perform multiple searches, it's best if you generate the "inverse" hash so you only need to iterate through the entire hash once instead of once per search.

---

If you are performing multiple searches, and they're not all for the same field, generate the inverse hash as follows:

```
my %key_by_field_and_value;
for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
   my $hash_for_key = $hash{$key};
   for my $field (keys(%$hash_for_key)) {
      my $hash_for_key_and_field = $hash_for_key->{$field};
      defined( my $date = get_any_one_key($hash_for_key_and_field) )
         or next;

      length( my $value = $hash_for_key_and_field->{$date} )
         or next;

      $key_by_field_and_value{$field}{$value} = $key;
   }
}
```

Then, a search becomes

```
my $field        = ...;
my $target_value = ...;

if (defined(
   my $target_key =
      do { no autovivification; $key_by_field_and_value{$field}{$target_value} }
)) {
   ...
}
```

---

If you are performing multiple searches, and they're all for the same field, generate the inverse hash as follows:

```
my $field = ...;

my %key_by_value;
for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
   my $hash_for_key = $hash{$key};
   defined( my $hash_for_key_and_field = $hash_for_key->{$field} )
      or next;

   defined( my $date = get_any_one_key($hash_for_key_and_field) )
      or next;

   length( my $value = $hash_for_key_and_field->{$date} )
      or next;

   $key_by_value{$value} = $key;
}
```

Then, a search becomes

```
my $target_value = ...;

if (defined( my $target_key = $key_by_value{$target_value} )) {
   ...
}
```

---

If you're just going to search once, you'll have to search the entire hash.

```
my $field        = ...;
my $target_value = ...;

my $target_key;
for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
   my $hash_for_key = $hash{$key};
   defined( my $hash_for_key_and_field = $hash_for_key->{$field} )
      or next;

   defined( my $date = get_any_one_key($hash_for_key_and_field) )
      or next;

   length( my $value = $hash_for_key_and_field->{$date} )
      or next;

   if ($value eq $target_value) {
      $target_key = $key;
      last;
   }
}

if (defined($target_key)) {
   ...
}
```

---

Both of the above solutions use this efficient version of `my ($key) = keys(%$h);`:

```
sub get_any_one_key {
   my ($h) = @_;
   my $key = each(%$h);
   keys(%$h);  # Reset iterator
   return $key;
}
```